# Dependency Injection in Custom Field Widget

Tags: 8, entities, dependency-injection

I am trying to inject the entity query service into a custom field widget.  This is the relevant code:

```
/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'address_options' widget.
 *
 * @FieldWidget(
 *   id = "address_options",
 *   label = @Translation("Addresses"),
 *   field_types = {
 *     "entity_reference"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class MyCustomWidget extends WidgetBase {

  /**
   * The entity query factory service.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\QueryFactory
   */
  protected $entityQuery;

  public function __construct($plugin_id, $plugin_definition, FieldDefinitionInterface $field_definition, array $settings, array $third_party_settings, QueryFactory $entity_query) {
    parent::__construct($plugin_id, $plugin_definition, $field_definition, $settings, $third_party_settings);
    $this->entityQuery = $entity_query;
  }

  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $configuration['field_definition'],
      $configuration['settings'],
      $configuration['third_party_settings'],
      $container->get('entity.query')
    );
  }
```

The following error results:

> Recoverable fatal error: Argument 6 passed to
>   Drupal\custom_module\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\AddressWidget::__construct()
>   must be an instance of Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\QueryFactory, none
>   given, called in
>   /homedir/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Field/WidgetPluginManager.php on line
>   130.

Is it not possible to use dependency injection in this case or am I missing something?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What you are missing is to implement \Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContainerFactoryPluginInterface, which defines the create() method.

See \Drupal\file\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\FileWidget for an example.

Comment: Awesome! Just made my day. :)